# JPA, Jackson deserialize JSON into Hashmap, result is empty

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have problem with deserializing JSON content into HashMap. I have following JSON to parse:

```
{"param":"p","infos":[{"b":2,"a":1}]}
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ArrayMapDeserializer.class)
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name="infoKey")
@Column(name="infoValue", length=400)
private Map<String, Integer> infos = new HashMap<>();
```

And here is ArrayMapDeserializer.java

```
public class ArrayMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Integer>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        if (jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
            return mapper.readValue(jp, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Integer>>() {
            });
        } else {
            mapper.readTree(jp);
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after checking if properly parsed object is in my database, map remains empty. It looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"param":"p","infos":{}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick guess: shouldn't it be `return mapper.readTree(jp);` instead of `return new HashMap<>();` in your `else` clause?

Comment: What purpose serve square bracket in `.... "infos":[{"b":2,"a":1}] ...`? They should be removed or `private Map<String, Integer> infos = new HashMap<>();` changed to list of HasMap(s). Or?